# Indexes was outside the bounds of the array c#

Tags: c#

```
DateTime[] start = new DateTime[] { new DateTime(1990, 1, 1), new DateTime(1995, 1, 1) };

DateTime[] end   = new DateTime[] { new DateTime(2000, 1, 1), new DateTime(2008, 1, 1) };

TimeSpan timespan;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       

    for (int i=0; i<2; i++)
    {         

        if (end[i] < end[i + 1] && start[i] < start[i + 1] && start[i + 1] >= end[i])            
            timespan = (end[i] - start[i]) + (end[i + 1] - end[i]); 


        /* if (end[i-1] < end[i] && start[i-1] < start[i] && start[i] >= end[i-1])            
            timespan = (end[i-1] - start[i-1]) + (end[i] - end[i-1])  */
    }                 

    int timeDifference = timespan.Days;
    MessageBox.Show(timeDifference.ToString());
}
```

Comment: This is not a question. Please explain what your problem is, expected and actual results, and what you have tried. You should follow the guidelines given by [sscce.org](http://sscce.org/) or [Writing the perfect question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx).

Comment: Hint: what is `end[i+1]` when `i` is `1` ?

Comment: Do start and end always contain 2 values ? If yes, why do you use an array ?

Comment: my question is to find timedifference datefrom ->1990-2000 and datefrom -> 1995 to 2008 and her timedifference should be (2000-1990)+(2008-2000) if there were 2 element i can find without array but here a lot of element and i should check all time ,but occurs error

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that when `i = 1` then `i + 1` is out of the bounds of the array.

Without knowing how you expect to work with the last element (when there is no next item) is hard to provide an alternative.

Comment: no it doesnot contain 2 values ,there many elements ,but i cut them

Answer (score 0):

```
end[i + 1]
```

when i goes from 0 to 1 will give an indexer of 2 (i.e. the third item in the array). Clearly, this is out of range when applied to an array of length 2.

Answer (score 0):

The problem looks straight forward.

When your loop iteration reaches i=1

your inner condition end[i] < end[i + 1]

will check end[1] < end[2] (which is outside the array index)

so change your looping

```
for (int i=0; i<end.Length -1; i++)
```

or

```
for (int i=0; i<1; i++)
```

Comment: i used both of them but again same error ((